# Bounce doesn't export some VST tracks in non realtime export

Tags: logic-pro

I started a brand-new project today and the audio export does not include any of some tracks. I can only hear them if I bounce them in place to audio (or realtime bounce), which clearly is not good for my workflow.

This problem has been preventing me using logic for months and it's still an issue with the latest version.

eg the first track isn't heard in a fast bounce (or bounce in place when selecting multi tracks), only a realtime.

[image]

i can do individual bounce in place but it sucks:

[image]

any advice?

Comment: Is it possible that some of the tracks not being bounced are muted? When exporting, are you sure you're selecting "All Tracks as Audio Files" ?  When bouncing, are you sure you're selecting "Bounce Project or Section" and selecting the desired sectiom?

Comment: According to [Apple's Logic Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/logicpro/lgcp785a41c3/mac) you cannot offline bounce midi tracks, could this be it?